# Fluent NHibernate Generated.Insert does not work as expected

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to auto generate a number for an entity from the `database` with the following mapping:

```
Map(m => m.No).Not.Nullable().ReadOnly().Unique().Generated.Insert();
```

Why is no value generated for the property "`No`" of type int?

This is not an identity column.

Answer (score 1):

You have it marked ReadOnly()? So it's not going to insert or update the value.